# onchange event how to pass date value to javascript

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

Inside a form using datepicker to get date and pass date value to javascript in onchange event,
i tried this code, but is not work.

```
    <form name="users" onchange="showUser(this.value)">     
    <label>Select By Date:</label>                          
    <?php 
    include 'connection/db_connection.php';
    echo '<div class="form-group">                              
    <input type="text" name="date2" value="" class="form-control" id="dt2" required />
    </div> ';
    ?>
    </form>
```

My script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function showUser(str) {
if (str=="") {
 document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML="";
return;
} 
if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
} else { // code for IE6, IE5
xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
 }
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200) {
  document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
 }
 }
 xmlhttp.open("GET","get_export.php?q="+str,true);
 xmlhttp.send();
 }
 </script>
```

I need to pass a date value and get the recods from mysql table using where clause

get_export.php:

```
<?php
$q = intval($_GET['q']);
 include 'connection/db_connection.php';
 $sql="SELECT * FROM admin_export where datetime='".$q."'";
 $result = mysql_query($sql);

 ?>
 <div class="table-responsive">
     <table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover">
     <thead>
         <?php
             echo "
                <th>SNO</th>
                <th>Item Code</th>
                 <th>Product Name</th>
                 <th>Quantity</th>
                 <th>Edit</th>
                  <th>Delete</th>

                     </tr>
                     </thead> 
                     <tbody>  ";
       while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) 
             {    
                  echo $row['sno']; // here not work

                    $sno=$row['sno'];
                     echo "<tr>";
                     echo "<td>" . $row['sno'] . "</td>";
                    echo "<td>" . $row['item_code'] . "</td>";
                     echo "<td>" . $row['product_name'] . "</td>";
                     echo "<td>" . $row['quantity'] . "</td>";
                    echo '<td><a href="edit_export.php?id='.$sno.'"> <img src="assets/img/icons/pencil.png" alt="Edit"></a></form></td>';

                    echo '<td> <form name="dform" action="delete_export.php?id='.$sno.'" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                    <input type="submit"  value="Delete"   class="btn btn-primary"></input></form></td> ';


             echo "</tr>";
            }
            echo "</tbody></table>";
            mysql_close($con);
            ?>
```

Comment: A form doesn't have a value ?

Comment: A forom **doesn't** have a value! - no question mark. you're using this.value in your form tag, what are you expecting to happen?

Comment: `this.value` on a `<form>`?

Comment: ok, how can i pass date value to script?

Comment: just get it from `id="dt2"` thats much convenient anyway. on submit form disable the default behavior. and watch out for that SQL injection vulnerability. Use a newer API preferably PDO with using prepared statements

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
<form name="users" onchange="showUser(this)">
```

which you can then access by saying:

```
function showUser(str)
{
  var val = str.value;
}
```

Comment: Sorry about that, my bad. I don't know which one you use, but if you use the bootstrap datepicker, you could check this link out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17009354/detect-change-to-selected-date-with-bootstrap-datepicker