# Validate bootstrap-datepicker field on change

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-datepicker

I'm trying to validate the order_datePicker input field when it is filled by bootstrap-datepicker. I've already found some answers on [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17009354/detect-change-to-selected-date-with-bootstrap-datepicker) but somehow I cant get it to work myself. With the other input fields i'm using:

```
$('#order_emailadres').on('input', function() {
```

However this isnt working for a datepicker input field because the user is not using input.

So, as mentioned in the [documentation](https://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.org/en/latest/events.html#changedate) and stackoverflow link i'm trying to catch the changeDate event so that the input can be validated by the following code:

HTML:

```
<div id=sandbox-container>
  <div id="datepicker"></div>
    <input type="text" id="order_datePicker" name=order_datePicker>
  </div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
$('#order_datePicker').on('changeDate', function () {
    var input=$(this);
    var re = /^[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{4}$/;
    var is_valid=re.test(input.val());
    if(is_valid){input.removeClass("invalid").addClass("valid");}
    else{input.removeClass("valid").addClass("invalid");}
});
```

Sadly this is not working. What am I doing wrong?

**Update:**

Got it working with the code below but now the class is added to the div instead of the input field. However the original question is answered. Thanks

```
$('#datepicker').datepicker().on('changeDate',function(){
    $('#order_datePicker').val($('#datepicker').datepicker('getFormattedDate'));
    var input=$(this);
    var re = /^[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{4}$/;
    var is_valid=re.test(input.val());
    if(is_valid){input.removeClass("invalid").addClass("valid");}
    else{input.removeClass("valid").addClass("invalid");}
});
```

Comment: `$('#order_datePicker').datepicker().on('changeDate',function(){});` this is the one you need to use right?

Comment: Do you instantiate the `.datepicker()`?

Comment: Yeah I tried that as well. No luck

Comment: You know that you don't just try that, it is required!

Comment: There's a question with what you're asking: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17429056/4274373

Comment: @A1rPun You're right. I was doing that in another part of the script. At this point I got it working however the class is added to the wrong div. It should add itself to the input field but it now adds itself to the div #datepicker. See update in post.

Comment: Class is added in input tag..check my snippet

Comment: @debin: that does not seem to work with the embedded version

Comment: because if u r using ur last snippet then  in that u used div id that is `#datepicker`..so `$(this)` will refer div tag instead of input..select input id that is `order_datePicker` as shown in mine..

Answer (score 0):

```js
$('#order_datePicker').datepicker();
$('#order_datePicker').change(function() {
  alert("date change");
$('#order_datePicker').datepicker();
$('#order_datePicker').change(function() {
 $('#order_datePicker').val($('#datepicker').datepicker('getFormattedDate'));
var input=$(this);
var re = /^[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{4}$/;
var is_valid=re.test(input.val());
if(is_valid){input.removeClass("invalid").addClass("valid");}
else{input.removeClass("valid").addClass("invalid");}
});

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.8.21/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.3.0/css/datepicker3.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.3.0/js/bootstrap-datepicker.js"></script>

<div id=sandbox-container>
  <div id="datepicker"></div>
  <input type="text" id="order_datePicker" name=order_datePicker/>
</div>
</div>
```

Try,
**UPDATED**

```
  $("#StateDatePicker").on("dp.change", function(e) { alert(); });
or 
$("#StateDatePicker").change( function(e) { alert(); });
```

please refer https://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/Events/ for events

Comment: Where did you find `dp.change` ?

Comment: I used it in my project..as I was facing same problem and it is already in event of datepicker

Comment: There is no `dp.change` on the bootstrap datepicker OP mentioned

Comment: have u visited mentioned site? @A1rPun

Comment: Yes, it is a different bootstrap datepicker, have you visted the site OP mentioned?

Comment: I do not think it is different..OP is using https://github.com/eternicode/bootstrap-datepicker and I have used its event