# How to get UI-Datepicker month change event

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-datepicker, bootstrap-datepicker

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rOkBW.png)

code:

```
$(function() {
        $("#businessDatepicker").datepicker({
            changeMonth: true,
            changeYear: true,
        });
    });
```

How to get month and year change event?

Comment: what do you mean by **get month and year change event**?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Detect change to selected date with bootstrap-datepicker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17009354/detect-change-to-selected-date-with-bootstrap-datepicker)

Answer (score 3):

```
$(function() {
        $("#businessDatepicker").datepicker({
            changeMonth: true,
            changeYear: true,
            onChangeMonthYear: function () {
                alert('y');
            }
        });
    });
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.