# bootstrap datepicker on change

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-datepicker

I have a bootstrap date picker  which i want to alert when date is changed buit it is working something different

i am trying with simple jquery `on.(change)` event so it is executing two times one when user clicks on datepicker icon and another when user selects the date

**CODE**

```js
$('#deliveryDate').datepicker({
  format: 'dd/mm/yyyy',
});
$("#deliveryDate").on("change", function(e) {
  alert("hi")
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/gijgo@1.9.6/css/gijgo.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/gijgo@1.9.6/js/gijgo.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<div class=" col-lg-3">
  <label for="deliveryDate" id="commonHeader"> Date:</label>
  <input type="text" id="deliveryDate" name="deliveryDate" width="176" />
</div>
```

I have tried

```
$("#deliveryDate").on("dp.change", function(e) {
    alert('date');
});
```

but this one is not working

what i am trying to do is when user selects the date then alert should come not on click of datepicker

Comment: dp.change works for datetimepicker.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6471959/jquery-datepicker-onchange-event-issue

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jQuery Datepicker onchange event issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6471959/jquery-datepicker-onchange-event-issue)

Comment: @Refilon that one is jquery date picker

Comment: @HarshwardhanSharma i am using date-picker only so there is no need to talk about date-time picker

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Detect change to selected date with bootstrap-datepicker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17009354/detect-change-to-selected-date-with-bootstrap-datepicker)

Comment: @manish thakur it was just for your info. check the duplicate post.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can compare the values, and when there are chagnes, trigger the alert

```js
$("#deliveryDate").datepicker({
  format: 'dd/mm/yyyy',
});

var lastValue = null;

$("#deliveryDate").on("change", function(e) {

  if(lastValue !== e.target.value){
    alert("hi");
    console.log(e.target.value);
    lastValue = e.target.value;
  }

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/gijgo@1.9.6/css/gijgo.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/gijgo@1.9.6/js/gijgo.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<div class=" col-lg-3">
  <label for="deliveryDate" id="commonHeader"> Date:</label>
  <input type="text" id="deliveryDate" name="deliveryDate" width="176" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

all you need to replace "change" to "focusout":
hope this helps you:

```js
$('#deliveryDate').datepicker({
  format: 'dd/mm/yyyy',
});
$("#deliveryDate").on("focusout", function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  alert("hi")
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/gijgo@1.9.6/css/gijgo.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/gijgo@1.9.6/js/gijgo.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<div class=" col-lg-3">
  <label for="deliveryDate" id="commonHeader"> Date:</label>
  <input type="text" id="deliveryDate" name="deliveryDate" width="176" />
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, Nemer, I've tried almost everything, didn't work except the focusout

Comment: Same for me! focusout is THE solution! THANKS!