# Detect changes in django-bootstrap-datepicker-plus with JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, django, django-forms

I am using django-bootstrap-datepicker-plus package, and I am trying to display an alert when the date is changed. However, jquery does not seem to detect any changes to the date.

Following this question [Detect change to selected date with bootstrap-datepicker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17009354/detect-change-to-selected-date-with-bootstrap-datepicker/) only works when I add the JQuery UI CDN to my code, which causes a problem as two datepickers appear. Is there a way to get JQuery to detect a change in django-bootstrap-datepicker without adding JQuery UI code?

```
forms.py

from django import forms
from bootstrap_datepicker_plus.widgets import DatePickerInput

class ExampleForm(forms.Form):
    DOB = forms.DateField(required=False, label="Date of Birth",
                input_formats=['%d/%m/%Y'],
        widget=DatePickerInput(format='%d/%m/%Y')
    )
```

Html

```
 <div class="col-12 col-md-6 mb-0 p-1">
      {{ form.DOB|as_crispy_field }}
    </div>
```

Rendered HTML
[image: Rendered HTML]

Comment: It is bootstrap datetimepicker, not the one from jQueryUI. To listen to this changes, you need to handle `dp.change` event, smth like `$('#id_DOB').on('dp.change', ev => myHandler(ev));`. See [ref](https://getdatepicker.com/4/Events/)

Comment: Thanks mate, worked. Want to add it as the answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a lot of JS packages with similar [date,time]picker functionality. `django-bootstrap-datepicker-plus` uses [eonasdan picker](https://getdatepicker.com/4/), [according to the docs](https://pypi.org/project/django-bootstrap-datepicker-plus/). They use different event names. Eonasdan implementation prefixes all events with `dp.` namespace, as stated [here](https://getdatepicker.com/4/Events/), so the following should work:

```js
$('#id_DOB').on('dp.change', ev => myHandler(ev));
```